# Find the volume of the shape rotating $x$-axis.

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Write and sketch the integral of intersection of $$y=\sqrt{x}, 
 \  y=\sqrt{8-x},   \  y=1$$

Then find the volume of the shape rotating around the $x$-axis.

I think there is something wrong while writing the integral. Could you help for this question if possible?

Comment: This will have three separate integration regions in terms of $x$ (or 2 if you use symmetry) using the disk method. If you rewrite in terms of $y$ you can integrate a single integral $0$ to $1$ using the shell method.

Comment: I found a rectangular and two different area. could you check if possible if it is right or not. this is image https://ibb.co/YNnj9bQ

Comment: In your image you calculate the area, but in the question you ask for the volume. Also, the area is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I meant in the comment.

**Shell Method:**

$$V=2\pi \int_0^1 y\cdot [(8-y^2)-y^2] \ dy$$

**Disk Method:**

$$ V=\pi \int_0^1 (\sqrt{x})^2 \ dx + \pi \int_1^7 (1)^2 \ dx +  \pi \int_7^8 (\sqrt{8-x})^2 \ dx$$

or (disk method, using symmetry)

$$ V=2\cdot \left[ \pi \int_0^1 (\sqrt{x})^2 \ dx +  \pi \int_1^4 (1)^2 \ dx\right]$$